# Resources consumed by build jobs in screwdriver.cd

Tags: screwdriver-cd

While deploying an instance of screwdriver.cd via [helm chart](https://github.com/screwdriver-cd/screwdriver-chart), where do we specify how much CPU every job would consume?

Every new build triggered currently via screwdriver spins up a pod consumes which request for below resources:

```
"resources": {
    "limits": {
        "cpu": "2",
        "memory": "2Gi"
    },
    "requests": {
        "cpu": "2",
        "memory": "2Gi"
    }
}
```

Where can we update/overwrite this in helm chart while deploying it? I don't want every build to consume 2 CPUs of my cluster.

I did update environment variables in the pipeline to use less CPU as instructed [here](https://github.com/screwdriver-cd/buildcluster-queue-worker/blob/59f62f4cebec11a958f35fbdc508c3ee400092d6/config/custom-environment-variables.yaml):

```
shared:
    environment:
        CPU: micro
        MEMORY: micro
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Helm chart, since builds run on LOW cpu and memory by default, you can configure the [default LOW values](https://github.com/screwdriver-cd/screwdriver-chart/blob/master/values.yaml#L74-L96) under the `queue` section in the `values.yaml` file.

---

To use less CPU and MEMORY in your Screwdriver pipeline, you'll need to use `screwdriver.cd/cpu` and `screwdriver.cd/ram` [annotations](https://docs.screwdriver.cd/user-guide/configuration/annotations#job-level-annotations) in your `screwdriver.yaml` file.

For example, to use `micro` CPU and MEMORY, you should have something like this:

```
shared:
    annotations:
        screwdriver.cd/cpu: MICRO
        screwdriver.cd/ram: MICRO
```